# Taking screenshots of youtube Videos with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, youtube

I have the URLs for about 600 youtube videos that I want to get a single screenshot from. Before I loop this over the entire url list I would like to get it to work for 1 video. But I have run into a host of issues.

1. Issue with Click
2. Issue where video screenshots don't render video, just elements (ie. playbutton, timecode, ect)
3. Not sure how to deal with occasional ads on videos. But this may not even be an issue.

1:

```
vid_xpath = '//*[@id="movie_player"]'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjlmFGO3fKE&t=110s'
driver.get(url)
#driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#click Play button
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ytp-large-play-button").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ytp-large-play-button").click()

#I would then Take the screen shot
```

My error is:

```
ElementNotInteractableException           Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/k9/wwjktzjs3lzg4xwn06htpryh0000gn/T/ipykernel_1601/155648964.py in <module>
     12 driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ytp-large-play-button").click()
     13 time.sleep(1)
---> 14 driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ytp-large-play-button").click()
     15 #I would then Take the screen shot
     16 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/macs40400/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in click(self)
     91     def click(self) -> None:
     92         """Clicks the element."""
---> 93         self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
     94 
     95     def submit(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/macs40400/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    408             params = {}
    409         params["id"] = self._id
--> 410         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    411 
    412     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None) -> WebElement:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/macs40400/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    442         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
...
webdriverClickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.sys.mjs:150:11
interaction.clickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.sys.mjs:119:11
clickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:198:29
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:86:31
```

2:
For the screenshots that are not appearing correctly I am using the code below: I have been testing the SS expecting to see the thumbnail as the click button does not work. All I see is a blank video box.

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,vid_xpath)
element.screenshot(".\\test.png")
```

3. Using the time codes in the youtube url I am able to watch 5s of the video without seeing an add. I believe this will be my work around, but havnt gotten far enough to really know for sure.

For 1.
I tried using the xpath instead of css-selector and the same issue occured, but on the first click instance

For 2.
I have tried changing the video xpath to:

- /html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ytd-player/div/div/div[1]/video
- //*[@id="movie_player"]
- //*[@id="ytd-player"]
- //*[@id="container"]

Comment: Q1 and Q2 figured out.

Comment: If you are interested in the first frame of videos, using [`yt-dlp`](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) with [`ffmpeg`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg) makes more sense in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

For,

1. The second click was not working because 'ytp-large-play-button' would no longer appear.

This worked

`driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ytp-large-play-button").click() time.sleep(1) driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ytp-play-button").click()`

2. There is now content in the video screenshots.
3. for some reason the 'driver.get(url)' does not use firefox the same way as the user, so when I copy and paste the url into the browser, I have 5s to watch. But when done using this API youtube refreshes and force loads the ad. This happens every time.

Comment: And finally which was the correct way to find the video, you didn't included that in yoour code: /html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ytd-player/div/div/div[1]/video
//*[@id="movie_player"]
//*[@id="ytd-player"]
//*[@id="container"]

Answer (score 0):

In the end I gave up on using a webdriver. I went ahead and used a mouse/keyboard controller to use my personal browser. This let me use my adblocker.

I'm sure this all could have been fixed with a webdriver built in add blocker, but I'm stupid.